# Forward VGA & USB over ethernet

Tags: usb, keyboard, display, ethernet, vga

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Touchscreen over Ethernet (with video?)](https://superuser.com/questions/89309/touchscreen-over-ethernet-with-video)

Is there a way to forward VGA & USB (basically the screen and the keyboard) over ethernet so that I can access the BIOS remotely? I know that Sun blades support this feature using a java client by connecting to the ilom, but is there a solution for other, random machines?

Kind regards

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/89309/touchscreen-over-ethernet-with-video/89334#89334

Comment: it's rather similar, yes, but it's not an exact duplicate as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are companies that make KVM devices that support Ethernet (usually via RDP or VNC).  It's extra hardware that you have to add, but works well.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wonder if there are any mainboards which have this feature as a build in functionality.

Comment: Seems like it'd be something that enterprise class mobos would have.  However, they all still seem to insist on their own proprietary ILOM solutions.  :-(

Comment: Hmm too bad :/. Implementing such KVM forwarding features on "all" mainboards would solve a lot of problems and especially simplify a lot of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine in question was [Virtualised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (ie, running in VirtualBox or VMWare), you could remotely access its bios settings via VNC/Remote Desktop to the host machine.